# How can I build a redirect URL in a magento 2 js component?

Tags: magento2, javascript, url

I have added a payment method renderer javascript file to a magento 2 module. I want one of the functions in the js to redirect to another page on the site.

How do I get the base url so that I can generate the full url correctly?

Currently I have this js method renderer:

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (quote, Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'VendorName_ModuleName/payment/mypaymentmethod'
            },

            startPayment: function(){
                var url = "modulename/mypaymentmethod/generatepaymentrequest"
                console.log(url);
                // TODO prepend base url before redirecting
                window.location.href = url;
            },
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `mage/url` module in the javascript to build the URL for you. Just call `build` with the path you want to append to the base URL and it will return the full URL.

To be specific; add `'mage/url'` to the list of modules at the start of the `define` statement and add an argument to the module's main function, I called it `urlBuilder` in my example. Then you can call `urlBuilder.build("some/path")` to generate a full URL.

Something like the following example:

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'mage/url'
    ],
    function (quote, Component, urlBuilder) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
               template: 'VendorName_ModuleName/payment/mypaymentmethod'
            },

            startPayment: function(){
                var url = urlBuilder.build("modulename/mypaymentmethod/generatepaymentrequest");
                window.location.href = url;
            },
        });
    }
);
```